# Programming a Button In Android Java to simulate HW Keyboard

Tags: java, android

I am writing an Android app in Java and want navigation button at the bottom (up, down, left, right, enter, escape (back), and brightness control).  My button presses look like this

```java
public void upButtonPressed(View view)
{
    BaseInputConnection bic = new BaseInputConnection(view, true);
    bic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SYSTEM_NAVIGATION_UP));
}
```

I have also tried

```java
public void upButtonPressed(View view)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
            inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP);
        }
    });
}
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?  Also, yes I need this, and yes the program works on a VM with my HW keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dispatchKeyEvent()` to dispatch a `KeyEvent` to a `View` for it to handle.

So, if you want the `view` to handle the `KeyEvent`, then,

```
public void upButtonPressed(View view)
{
    view.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SYSTEM_NAVIGATION_UP));
}
```

Else, if you want the `Activity` to handle the `KeyEvent`, then,

```
public void upButtonPressed(View view)
{
    dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SYSTEM_NAVIGATION_UP));
}
```

Comment: Thanks much! This worked for the "Enter" Button.  However, I cannot get the 4 pack of arrows from a keypad to work. Is there a special key for that?

Comment: I guess you're probably looking for the following key events : `KEYCODE_DPAD_UP`, `KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN`, `KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT` & `KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT`.

Comment: I tried those too, it there a key for NUMPAD_DOWN or similar, that works on my HW Keyboard?

Comment: I was unable to find a separate key event for `NUMPAD_DOWN` in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent). And I'm unsure as to whether they share the KeyEvent with the normal arrow keys.

Comment: I know that `KEYCODE_DPAD_UP` & the rest are used for directional keys, but you'll probably have to test if they work the same for HW keyboard & numpad arrow keys.